# Using objects that are declared in different files across the whole project

Tags: c++, class, include

I have a C++ project that has multiple files.

File A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
   class A
   {
      void somefunctionA();
   };
   A a;
#endif
```

File B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
   class B
   {
      void somefunctionB();
   };
   B b;
#endif
```

I want to use object `a` in class `B` and object `b` in class `A`
So basically I want to use variables `a` and `b` anywhere in the program.

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
...
```

But there is a conflict. Object "a" isn't seen in class B.
What can be done in this situation and is there a better approach?

Comment: Don't *define* variables in header file. Think about what would happen if you include the header files in multiple source files.

Comment: maybe that's my problem. where should I define them? I want them to be super global.

Comment: An object oriented solution would be the Singleton pattern

Comment: @jasal The singleton pattern is overused and mostly frowned upon. In this case a singleton object is hardly the proper solution.

Comment: why not? as I think now, Singleton would be pretty nice here. I tried your solution and compiler gives errors invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A'

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think the real problem is global objects being overused. This has nothing to do with the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *declare* a class anywhere, like in an unrelated header file.

For example:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

// Declaration of class A
class A;

extern A a;

class B
{
    void somefunctionB();
};

extern B b;

#endif
```

Now in the implementation of e.g. `B::somefunctionB` you can use the variable `a` without seeing the definition of the variable. You do need the definition of the `A` class though.

---

A *declaration* is basically you telling the compiler that something exists, what type it is and what name it have. It's like function prototypes, you *declare* that somewhere there is a definition of a function, but after the function prototype declaration you can call the function without having seen the function definition (implementation).

A *definition*, on the other hand, is what tells the compiler (and later the linker) that "this is it". The definition of a variable is not only telling the compiler that the variable exists, but also instructs the compiler to reserve space for the variable in the resulting executable program. A definition of a function is the actual implementation of of the function, where you have the code inside the function.

Incidentally, if a variable or function haven't been declared then the compiler sees the definition of the variable or function, then the definition is also the declaration.

---

If, as you state, you have all code for the classes inline in the class definition you will have a problem using the global variables with only a class declaration, you need the complete class definition. But if you use class `A` in class `B` and the other way around, you have a circular dependency that is hard to break: Class `A` needs class `B` to work, but class `B` needs class `A` to work.

The easiest solution to break this circular dependency is to put the code from class `A` that uses class `B` in a separate source file, and the same for the code in class `B` that uses class `A`. This way the header files will not need to include each other giving you the circular dependency, and the source files can include both header files without problems.

Comment: @user3485986 That is a *declaration*. I've updated my answer with what a declaration is.

Comment: So instead of A a; I should write extern A a; in A.h?

Comment: @user3485986 Yes that's correct. And in *one* source file you *define* the variable, like you currently do in the header file.

Comment: what id I don't have source files? I mehtods are written in .h file as well. Is it very bad?

Comment: @user3485986 It depends. But if you have global variable you *must* define them in a source file. And you *do* have a source file: the `main.cpp` file. simply place the definitions there.

Comment: with or without extern keyword?

Comment: I put all class A implementation in A.cpp file but still it dones't recognize b

Answer (score 1):

Use the singleton pattern for implementing classes that should have only a single global instance:

```
class A
{
public:
  static A& instance()
  {
    static A instance_;
    return instance_;
  }

  virtual ~A() {}

private:
  A() {}                   // prevent direct instantiation

  A(const A&);             // prevent copy construction
  A& operator=(const A&);  // prevent assignment
};
```

Then use `A::instance()` wherever you need to interact with the object instance.

Of course this pattern **should be used sparingly**. Make sure that you really need a global object before creating one and that there is no other way which will give you the same functionality.

Please note that this pattern is **not suitable for global objects that depend on each other** as the order of static initialization is undefined.